# A Fateful Day at the Theater

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

8 minors (around 8 years of age) walked into a dine-in theater in the fifth district of town and took a seat at the bar, filling 8 of 10 available chairs.
“Wine please,” said Don, the largest of the group.
The staff measured them up and said: “You’re too young to be here.”
“Fine,” Don replied. “We’ll take sodas.”

A quarter of the children are wearing white shirts.
The kids immediately next to Franz wore different color shirts.
Ed sat between an empty seat and someone on a tall chair.
Franz, Freida, and Fritz wore black shirts and received normal sodas.
George, Greta, and Gisela sat on the same size of chairs.
The two who wore hats had a lower chair than the person immediately to their left.
Gisela and Fritz were each holding hands with both their neighbors.
Freida was not sitting next to someone wearing a hat.
One of the hat wearers received a flat soda. The rest received normal sodas.
The one wearing a tie and hat sat on a lower chair than anyone else.
George was the closest one to their house keys, which they’d hung near the door by the ‘Open’ sign.
Don sat on the far end of the bar, furthest from their keys.
Each had the same four letter nickname that could be anagrammed to another of their nicknames.

What was their seating order and shared nicknames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minors are ...

> ... **musical notes**. The first letter of their names indicate the pitches D through G. The height of the seats also indicates the pitch as in the stave. White shirts are full or half notes with empty heads; black shirts are notes with filled heads. The hats are a [fermata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermata). The house keys are the clef. The flat soda indicates the flat note E♭ given (indirectly) by the [C minor key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_minor). The empty seats are rests. The notes holding hands with their neighbours are eigth notes that are connected with a bar. The tie is a [tie between notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music)). Finally, the nickname "note" anagrams to "tone".

The seating arrangement ...

> ... places these notes as the opening of [**Beethoven's Fifth Symphony**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._5_(Beethoven)).

> [image: musical notes]

> That could probably have been worked out from the statements, but the "fifth district in town" was a heavy hint that was too good to ignore. What can I say? Everything fits! Da-da-da-daaah!